# Can a transaction span multiple statements in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Is this possible in vb.net

```
sub Main()
    conn.open
    transactions = conn.begintransaction("SAMPLE")
    insertintotable1()
    insertintotable2()
    insertintotable3()
    transactions.commit
end sub
sub insertintotable1
    try
    conn = new sql connection(connectionstring)
    strsql = sql statement
    cmd = new sql command(strsql, conn)
    cmd.executenonquery
    catch ex as exception
         transaction.rollback
    end try
 end sub
sub insertintotable2
    try
    conn = new sql connection(connectionstring)
    strsql = sql statement
    cmd = new sql command(strsql, conn)
    cmd.executenonquery
    catch ex as exception
         transaction.rollback
    end try
 end sub
sub insertintotable3
    try
    conn = new sql connection(connectionstring)
    strsql = sql statement
    cmd = new sql command(strsql, conn)
    cmd.executenonquery
    catch ex as exception
         transaction.rollback
    end try
 end sub
```

My problem is that without transactions if I have a problem with my query in the 2nd table, table 1 data has already been inserted.  SO i looked up transactions and in theory it would solve that issue because you can roll back the insert if something failed.

Comment: Why don't you write a stored procedure, then the transaction is all contained in a single atomic unit you either call or don't call, and it either succeeds or doesn't succeed? Except for the fact that I don't know what all your `strsql` things are doing, or when each sub might be called, I don't understand the benefit of adding your own transaction layer on top of SQL Server's own in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that you need to instance one Sql connection and then pass it to the methods that will do the work on it. At the moment you are instancing a new connection in each method, so each one has it's own transaction.

Comment: Sweet,  What I did was   cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn, transactions)